# Insert from one table into another

Tags: c#, sql-server

I'm making a project in **C#** with **SQL** database and I need to take data from one table (Books) and put it in another table (Users).

The function I'm trying to make it's called "LoanBooks" and so far I managed to create a new record in Users by copying the Name column but only if I delete this part from the code : `AND (SELECT Username from dbo.Users WHERE Username like('%" + text + "%'))`

What I want to do is copy the “Name” column from “Books” to “Users” by giving a certain “Username” and “Name” via textbox.

```
class User
{
    SqlConnection con;
    SqlCommand cmd;
    SqlDataAdapter adpt;
    DataTable dt;
    string Username;
    string Password;
    string Name;
    public User(String aUser, String aPassword)
    {
        Username = aUser;
        Password = aPassword;
        con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=SILVIU-ASUS-N55;Initial Catalog=BooksDB;Integrated Security=True;Pooling=False");
    }
    public User(String aUser, String aPassword,string aName)
    {
        Username = aUser;
        Password = aPassword;
        Name = aName;
        con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=SILVIU-ASUS-N55;Initial Catalog=BooksDB;Integrated Security=True;Pooling=False");
    }
    public void SaveUser()
    {
        con.Open();
        cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO dbo.Users(Username,Password)  VALUES('" + Username + "','" + Password + "')", con);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();
    }
    public void DeleteUser(string Username)
    {
        con.Open();
        cmd = new SqlCommand("DELETE FROM dbo.Users WHERE Username = '" + Username + "'", con);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();
    }
    public void ShowUsers(DataGridView data)
    {
        adpt = new SqlDataAdapter("Select * from Users", con);
        dt = new DataTable();
        adpt.Fill(dt);
        data.DataSource = dt;
    }
    public void ShowLoanUsers(DataGridView data)
    {
        adpt = new SqlDataAdapter("Select Username,Name from Users", con);
        dt = new DataTable();
        adpt.Fill(dt);
        data.DataSource = dt;
    }
    public void SearchUser(DataGridView data, string text)
    {
        try
        {
            adpt = new SqlDataAdapter("Select * from Users where Username like('%" + text + "%')", con);
            dt = new DataTable();
            adpt.Fill(dt);
            data.DataSource = dt;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
    public void SearchLoanUser(DataGridView data, string text)
    {
        try
        {
            adpt = new SqlDataAdapter("Select Username,Name from Users where Username like('%" + text + "%')", con);
            dt = new DataTable();
            adpt.Fill(dt);
            data.DataSource = dt;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
    public void LoanBook(string text,string text1)
    {

        con.Open();
        cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO dbo.Users (Name) SELECT Name FROM dbo.Books WHERE Name like('%" + text1 + "%'), AND (SELECT Username from dbo.Users WHERE Username like('%" + text + "%'))", con);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();
    }
}
```

This is the main:

```
public partial class frmUser : Form
{
    User temp;
    Books temp1;
    public frmUser()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        temp = new User("", "", "");
        temp1 = new Books("", "", "", 0);
    }
    private void btnBack_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        frmLogin f = new frmLogin();
        this.Hide();
        f.ShowDialog();
        this.Close();
    }

    private void btnExit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Close();
    }

    private void btnLoanBook_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        temp.LoanBook(txtUsername.Text, txtBookName.Text);
    }

    private void btnSearchBook_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        temp1.SearchBook(dgvBooks, txtSearchBook.Text);
    }
    private void btnSearchUser_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        temp.SearchLoanUser(dgvUsers, txtSearchUser.Text);
    }

    private void btnShowUsers_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        temp.ShowLoanUsers(dgvUsers);
    }

    private void btnShowBooks_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        temp1.ShowBooks(dgvBooks);
    }
}
```

Comment: Yikes, that's some scary-wrong password handling, and the sql is crazy-vulnerable to injection issues. Those two things are too important to do wrong, even for testing/learning/proof of concept code.

Comment: I know the password handling it’s wrong and that is vulnerable, it’s a project for school, not supposed to go public and I’m not giving it much importance.

Comment: I say again, this is something too important even to let slide in learning projects.

Comment: What should I do to make it safe and good? I’m new at this

Answer (score 0):

I am not exactly sure what the question is so I will try to interpret it the best way that I can.  It would help if you are able to provide what your table structure looks like.  If I am understanding the question correctly, you want your LoanBook function to update the users table.  While this is completely doable I would strongly recommend doing some reading on third normal form. (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Third_normal_form)  With any relational database (SQL, Oracle, etc.) your goal is to keep the amount of repetitive data limited.  Right now with this example what happens if a user were to check out multiple books?  I imagine this is something you would like to happen but think about all of the data that you are going to repeat.

Table User

Columns
FirstName  MiddleName  LastName  BookCheckedout  etc, etc, etc,

```
Silviu     A           Szabo     Green Eggs and Ham
Silviu     A           Szabo     Go Dog Go
Silviu     A           Szabo     How the Grinch Stole Christmas
```

So why this seems perfectly fine, whats happening is that you are repeating the first 3 columns (Silviu A Szabu) and that takes up space in a database that is not required or good practice.  A better option would be to make a cross reference table.  A Users table, a Books Table, and also a UsersBooks table or LoanedBooks table.  Users table would just have a single record for Silviu and Books would create a single record for a specific book.  The Cross Reference table would contain all the records for the books that were checked out.

Table User

Columns
UserId(PrimaryKey) FirstName  MiddleName  LastName

```
1              Silviu     A           Szabo     
2              Stephen    A           S    
3              Darth      A           Vader
```

Table Books

Columns
  BookId(PrimaryKey)  Book

```
1                 Green Eggs and Ham
2                 Go Dog Go
3                 How the Grinch Stole Christmas
```

Table Users_Books_XRef

Columns
UserId(ForeignKey)  BooksId(ForeignKey)

```
1                1
1                2
1                3
```

From there you would just need to pass the userid into the crossref table for the book that was checked out.

Comment: Would you help me with the code in c# for what are you proposing? Thanks

Answer (score -1):

So looking at the first bit of code I see that you have two classes called User and the only difference is the aName.  Would it make more sense to have one class and anytime you would want to call it without passing aName you just pass null or a default value?

Comment: This is more suited to a comment than an answer.

Comment: Because I formed an answer in the form of a question?

Comment: As best I can see it doesn't answer the question, and is just a question for clarification/guidance. Also your other answer starts "I am not exactly sure what the question is" which is a clear indicator you shouldn't be attempting to [answer the question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) (see answer well asked questions).